# Is there any way to clear all tables using Liquibase?

Tags: postgresql, unit-test, liquibase

I'm currently using Liquibase for creating test data in my database before each test run.

I came across a problem where some of the test cases need special data, while others need the tables to be empty.

So I decided to give Liquibase contexts a try and only insert the data I really need for the current testcase plus - in an abstract superclass - all the data every test case needs (user accounts and stuff)...

I would like to clear the tables before each run, however I can't seem to find anything for this case except `dropAll()`, which seems to be overkill...

I'm not quite sure if it is even possible - because of foreign keys and other constraints - but I wonder if there is a way to delete the content of ALL the tables without dropping them completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the fastest way would be to use a custom sql tag that uses  `truncate ... cascade` on all "top-level" tables.

Using the `cascade` keyword for truncate will also (recursively) delete all rows from all dependent tables (all tables referencing the one that is being truncated).

Something like:

```
<sql>
   truncate table parent_1, parent_2, foobar cascade;
</sql>
```

Don't know if that is feasible with the number of tables you have or not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :-) Since I don't know if it's feasible (and because "dropAll()" runs for at least 10min now without any visible success), I'll go talk to someone who's in charge (:P) and tell him about it ... :-)

Comment: @gilaras: if a `dropAll()` takes that long, I would suspect some locking, e.g. transactions still referencing the tables that are to be dropped. If that is the case you would have the same problem with `truncate`.

Comment: you're right, there was something wrong that made the dropAll() take so long; my IDE thought it would be funny to import a wrong package (long live auto-completion!) ... so there was a loop somewhere ... now that I told which package to import by hand, everything works ;-) Thanks! :)